# Вид сайта по ссылке в мессенджерах

Tags: html, html5

у меня вопрос как поменять вид сайта в мессенджерах например телеграм
если отправить комуто ссылку тогда откроеться описания сайта в телеграме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как изменить заголовок , надпись и картинку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо в `head` страницы добавить:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="">
```

где:

**og:title** - заглавие страницы

**og:site_name** - название сайта

**og:description** - описание страницы

**og:image** - ссылка на картинку

Answer (score 1):

Мы используем следующую конструкцию для полного покрытия всех соц.сетей:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcRS6.png

````
    <title>Заголовок</title>
    <meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Заголовок"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Название сайта"/>
    <meta property="og:long_title" content="Заголовок + Лид/Описание">
    <meta name="description" content="Лид/Описание страницы">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Лид/Описание страницы"/>
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Лид/Описание страницы">
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="Ссылка на изображение 1200х630"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
    <meta property="vk:image" content="Ссылка на изображение 1200х630"/>
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="Ссылка на изображение 1200х630"/>```
````